# Returning c_char_p from Python ctypes: does the result have to be copied, and if so, how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a function in a library that returns a null-terminated char *, so setup in Python as:

```
my_lib = ctypes.CDLL("my_lib")
my_lib.my_func.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```

and this seems to work fine:

```
my_bytes = my_lib.my_func()
print(my_bytes)
```

However, the library manages its own memory, and so may manipulate the memory pointed to by `char *` later on. To make sure `my_bytes` never actually changes, does it need to be copied to another Python object, or has it *already* been copied? If it does need to be copied, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already been copied.  A `c_char_p` return is automatically converted to an immutable Python `bytes` object.  If the return type was `POINTER(c_char)` *then* you would have a pointer to the actual memory.  Sometimes you need the explicit type if you need to pass that pointer to a function to free the memory later.

A quick proof:

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('msvcrt')
dll.strcpy.argtypes = c_char_p,c_char_p
dll.strcpy.restype = c_char_p

# strcpy returns a pointer to the destination buffer 'b'
b = create_string_buffer(30)
b2 = dll.strcpy(b,b'hello, world!')
print(b2)
b[0] = b'm'     # alter the destination
print(b.value)
print(b2)       # no change to b2
print()
dll.strcpy.restype = POINTER(c_char)
b3 = dll.strcpy(b,b'hello there!')
print(b3)
print(b3[:12])
b[0] = b'm'     # alter the destination
print(b.value)
print(b3[:12])  # changed!
```

Output:

```
b'hello, world!'
b'mello, world!'
b'hello, world!'       # no change

<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x000001B65E9A5840>  # the pointer
b'hello there!'        # copied data from pointer
b'mello there!'        # change destination buffer
b'mello there!'        # cpoied data from pointer again, changed!
```

Answer (score 1):

`c_char_p` by default returns bytes object. So it will print with `b'` bytes. If need to print as string, we can do with `.decode('utf-8')`

**Example:**

```
print(b2) # prints b'hello, world!' as bytes
print(b2.decode('utf-8')) # prints 'hello, world!' as string
```